# g++ header included: still doesn't find definition

Tags: c++, include, makefile, g++, header-files

Good evening :)

I'm playing around with g++ and makefiles. I've gotten to this point:

foo.h:

```
#ifndef _FOO_H_
#define _FOO_H_

#include "bar.h"

class foo {
private:
    bar something;
public:
    bool start();
    bool stop();
};

#endif // _FOO_H_
```

Foo.h is eventually included in my main cpp file so I can set things in motion by calling start/stop.

```
void somewhere() {
    foo* hihi = new foo;
    hihi->start();
    delete hihi;
}
```

Then there's bar.h:

```
#ifndef _BAR_H_
#define _BAR_H_

class bar {

};

#endif // _BAR_H_
```

g++ doesn't seem to like it however:

```
g++  (some_flags) -c main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:2:
foo.h:8: error: ‘bar’ does not name a type
```

I'm using makefiles, and tried a combination of things like:

```
main.o: main.cpp foo.h bar.h
```

Even though I don't think I should have to add bar.h here, shouldn't including it in foo.h be enough?

To clarify, this is roughly how it's set up now (yes I know this can be done in a more efficient manner):

```
main.o: main.cpp foo.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.cpp

foo.o: foo.h foo.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c foo.cpp

bar.o: bar.h bar.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c bar.cpp
```

What's going on? I figure it's something I'm missing about g++ and the way it handles header includes, point me in the right direction please!

**edit - found the solution:**

Doh! I feel dumb right now.
Was messing around with boost::asio and kind of forgot I still left this on top of my headers somewhere:
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

Let's just say there's a boost::asio::ip::tcp::bar function :D

Oh well, thanks anyway!

Comment: Are you sure it's picking up the right bar.h? GCC 3.4.5 does not complain about this for me.

Comment: one piece of advice. *never* put a using directive in a header. In a .cpp file, that's fine, but in a header you're just asking for this type of problem to happen.

Comment: @Evan: I'll try to keep it in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Was messing around with boost::asio and kind of forgot I still left this on top of my headers somewhere: using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
>
> Let's just say there's a boost::asio::ip::tcp::bar function

[Dan Saks explains](http://www.ddj.com/article/printableArticle.jhtml?articleID=184403396&dept_url=/cpp/) some reasons why you should typedef your class names, even though it might seem redundant.

Well, you've run into real life situation where typedefing a class would have probably helped you find your problem a little easier:

```
 class bar {
 // ...
 };
 typedef class bar bar;
```

Generates this more meaningful message if there's a function named `bar()` already declared:

```
In file included from C:\temp\foo.h:4,
                 from C:\temp\test.cpp:4:
C:\temp\bar.h:7: error: `typedef class bar bar' redeclared as different kind of symbol
C:\temp\test.cpp:1: error: previous declaration of `void bar(int)'
C:\temp\bar.h:7: error: declaration of `typedef class bar bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

Double check everything. If you include `bar.h` into `foo.h`, the compiler should not raise up an error. Do you include `foo.h` from `bar.h`? Better don't do this because that would cause a circular dependency between headers, which will cause that kind of bugs.

Also check for spelling of header guards. This can be a common source of annoyance:

```
#ifdef _BAR_H_ // OOPS! we wanted #ifndef
#define _BAR_H_

class bar {

};

#endif // _BAR_H_
```

In addition, you should avoid putting the underscore before your header guard macro name. These names are reserved to the compiler. Call it `INCLUDED_BAR_H` or just `BAR_H_` instead.

Comment: This wasn't exactly the solution to my problem, but +1 for the info, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Tommy Hui and litb have already pointed to two probable causes; here's some background information that will hopefully come in useful.

First off, this has nothing to do with makefiles. A makefile is just a convenience thing that calls g++ for you, nothing more.

This stuff with header files can be a bit tricky to understand at first, especially once you get into circular dependencies. It really helped me to realize these three things:

- A `#include` is nothing more than a copy/paste operation, inserting the contents of the included file at that point.
- Everything must have been *declared* before it is used. Sometimes, when circular dependencies crop up, you might need to predeclare a class (e.g. `class bar;`) in another header.
- If, at the point of usage, any more information about the type is needed than just its existence, then the type's *definition* is needed as well. This goes for e.g. calling of a method on an object of that type, but also for including a field of that type! (Not for a pointer to an object of that type, though, because pointers are all the same size.)

Comment: This wasn't exactly the solution to my problem, but +1 for the info, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the main.cpp, you'll need to add the following line at the top of the file:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

Comment: bar.h is included in foo.h which is included in main.cpp

Comment: If that line were missing, then we wouldn't see a message about line 8 of foo.h as the "file included from main.cpp:2."